# Can I run a program as my Win10 wallpaper? (Similar to Android Live Wallpapers)

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

Is there any way for me to run a program as a wallpaper? Just run an exe persistently in the background. It'd essentially be my own 'wallpaper application'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. In Vista Microsoft created [DreamScene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_DreamScene) which was only a video which play under the desktop. This was removed in Windows 7 and Microsoft never added something like this again.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, depending on the EXE and depending on your skill, it's possible to have an application run as your desktop background.

1. The best option is to write a program or script that creates the right kind of window. This is not easy, but it is possible. There are Python scripts that demonstrate doing this in only a few hundred lines of code. This offers the most flexibility and efficiency and least cost.
2. There is a Free Open-Source program called Lively that facilitates adding most things (image, video, web page, Unity Engine Game/Application, etc) as your desktop background. Its features are not as broad as some paid programs, and it's not quite as efficient.
3. There is a cheap ($4-$5 USD) program called Wallpaper Engine that offers more features and better performance than Lively.

There are other paid wallpaper programs as well. You'll need to experiment with each option to find out which one suits your particular purposes.